# Authenticating apps as users in an API

Tags: api, authentication

I have a question about API authentication/authorization. I may have some trouble articulating the question, so bear with me.

First of all, I understand how to authenticate *end users* via an API. That's no mystery to me.

What I want to do is authenticate certain *apps* as users of my API. I would have some roles so that each user would have different privileges depending on that user's role. You can do different things depending on whether you're one of my mobile apps or you're some third-party API consumer.

Has anyone done this sort of thing, where you have not end users talking to an API, but "app users"? Is there any documentation you can point me to about it? Does this practice have a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of authentication is known as application authentication (as opposed to user authentication).

Twitter provides a good overview of how to achieve this with Twitter applications. The article also serves as a good introduction to the general practice of application authentication.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth